# How to fix runtime error '430' and other automation errors in vba for excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have recently written some code for the company I work at in VBA for Excel. The purpose of the code is to run through a list of entered part numbers on Excel, search their respective URL, and then save that webpage as a PDF to the selected folder.

I wrote this code using some inspiration and code from other projects I have seen and also had to add some of my own.

**My problem is this:**
The code I put here works flawlessly on my computer. I have test ran it many times with many different numbers and it works as intended every time. That being said, I sent this to my adviser via email for him to use because I was making this Excel project for him.

When he opened it on the day I sent it, it worked perfectly for him as it had for me. The next day he tried to run it and started getting automation errors I had never seen like

> run-time error '430'

and a few other similar errors.

Does anyone have any idea why the program would work one day and not the next and/or if there is a solution to it?

I'm mainly confused why it would suddenly stop working for him (it does still run perfectly on my computer). Also, for the code below it does follow a real link I just change website parts to "url" for the sake of company privacy.

Although, I don't think that matters anyways because I believe the code is following the first link properly and then has errors when it has to loop through more than one part number.

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
"URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Function DownloadFile(URL As String, LocalFilename As String) As Boolean
    Dim lngRetVal As Long
    lngRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, LocalFilename, 0, 0)
    If lngRetVal = 0 Then DownloadFile = True
End Function

Sub DownloadItemPDF()
    Dim strPDFLink As String
    Dim strPDFFile As String
    Dim doc, hcol, text As Variant
    Dim itemNum As Long
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")         
    IE.Visible = False

    MsgBox "Select Folder to Save .pdf to"
    Dim FolderName As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show

        On Error Resume Next
        strDir = .SelectedItems(1)
        Err.clear
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Range("H3").Select

    For count = 1 To 15
        If Not Selection.Value = "" Then        
            itemNum = Selection.Value
            strPDFLink = "url" & itemNum & "url"
            strPDFFile = strDir & "/Drawing2D_" & itemNum & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyy.mm.dd") & ".pdf"
            IE.Navigate strPDFLink
            Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
            Result = DownloadFile(strPDFLink, strPDFFile)
        End If

        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next count
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that we need an exact error message and the line in which the error occurs to be able to help you properly. Note that `On Error Resume Next` hides all error messages until `On Error GoTo 0` therefore if an error occurs in between you will never notice that means if `strDir = .SelectedItems(1)` fails your code will continue with `strDir` beeing empty for example. • Also get rid of all `.Select`, `Selection` and `ActiveSheet` statements, therfore read: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ These are two of the errors he got: Run-time error '430':

Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface

Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':

Automation error
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.                                                     Also, I know .Select probably isn't the most efficient method of running through numbers, but that part of the code is working for him.

Comment: In which line do the errors occur?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ He gets the errors on the DO UNTIL line in the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. I re-organized it and made it more stable. Also I included an error handling to prevent any hidden IE processes in the background.

```
Public Sub DownloadItemPDF()
    MsgBox "Select Folder to Save .pdf to"

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show

        On Error Resume Next 'hide all error messages
        Dim strDir As String
        strDir = .SelectedItems(1)
        'check if an error occured and exit sub if something went wrong otherwise yo u end up with an empty strDir 
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "No valid folder was picked.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'better define a concrete sheet: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName")
                                      'because ActiveSheet might be the wrong one!

    Dim CheckRange As Range
    Set CheckRange = ws.Range("H3").Resize(RowSize:=15)

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = False

    On Error GoTo QUIT_IE 'if an error occurs make sure the invisible IE gets closed

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In CheckRange
        If Not Cell.Value = vbNullString Then
            Dim itemNum As Long
            itemNum = Cell.Value

            Dim strPDFLink As String
            strPDFLink = "url" & itemNum & "url"

            Dim strPDFFile As String
            strPDFFile = strDir & "/Drawing2D_" & itemNum & "_" & Format$(Now, "yyyy.mm.dd") & ".pdf"

            IE.navigate strPDFLink
            Do While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

            Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
            Dim Result As Boolean
            Result = DownloadFile(strPDFLink, strPDFFile)
        End If
    Next Cell

QUIT_IE:
    IE.Quit 'don't forget to quit IE in case of error otherwise it will stay open invisible
    Set IE = Nothing
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error occured while trying to load:" & vbCrLf & strPDFLink & vbCrLf & "To:" & vbCrLf & strPDFFile
        Debug.Print "strPDFLink:", strPDFLink
        Debug.Print "strPDFFile:", strPDFFile
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for doing that! I tested it on my computer and it works well. I'm just awaiting the response from my adviser to see if it fixed his problems. Thanks for all the help!